How to change the text color of the selected item in html selector with size
I have the following CSS to change the colors of HTML <select> element with size attribute:
select[size] option:checked {
    background: linear-gradient(var(--color-selected-back) 0%, var(--color-selected-back) 100%);
    color: var(--color-selected);
}

The background color works properly (although I don't quite understand why I have to use linear-gradient for a solid color, but it doesn't work otherwise).
The browser seems to ignore the foreground color.

Does this mean I can't use a pure CSS solution?

The native <select> element is highly host-specific and very limited in styling.  Generally if you want more control over its styling then you'd replace it with something custom.
